# How do I get a precompiled binary for glu?

Tags: opengl, precompiled, glu

I have MinGW and MSys set up on a windows 7 machine, but the glu libraries that came with it are old, and dont support gluBuild3DMipmaps. I have searched everywhere for a precompiled glu library for MinGW that I can use, but I can't find anything... I can't even find documentation on how to build one.

So where do I get the newest version of glu?

Comment: Any reason not to use `glGenerateMipmap()` or `GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP`?

Comment: I like that solution. It solves my problem, but what about the ultimate problem of updating glu?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to pull out the Mesa/SGI [implementation](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/tree/src/glu?h=7.8).